# Onclick event not working with submit type button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to PHP and HTML nad am working on a web page with a form and submit button, and i want to make submit button as a ref button too i.e it will refer to some other page after submitting information to database. My problem is, with i connect the page with php and forward information with database, onclick event does nothing otherwise it works fine. I have tried

```
    onclick="location.href='https://www.google.com';">
```

and i even tired to make a function to refer to some link and called it in onclick event but of no use.

P.S

Sorry if i have asked something funny.

Comment: At first: your question is nothing to say sorry about.

If you want to redirect a user after submitting data, you should use PHP's `header()` as @Ram Sharma mentioned, so you send the user (including data) to the PHP and then the PHP sends the user to whatever you set the header-location to.

And maybe this information is also useful: you can send a formular even without clicking the submit-button, e.g. if you hit enter in an input-field.
If you want to replace the submit-action with another action, have a look at this tutoral: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this as Ram Sharma has suggested

```
 <form method="post" action="mypage.php">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="RN">
    <button type='submit' name="submit" value="Submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

then in mypage.php

```
    if($_POST['submit']){
       //save to database 
        header("Location: myotherpage.php");
       exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `window.location`

```
onclick="window.location='https://www.google.com'"
```

but instead of using the onclick attribute, you should attach the event directly to the element.
If you use jquery, this could be

```
<button id="mybutton" />
```

and the script

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function(e) {
    window.location = "http://www.google.com";
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

but in this case, your form isn't submitted. If you want to submit the form to the server, and then redirect, you should use

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
```

which is an http redirect, after your script is executed

Answer (score 0):

There can be different ways

1) You can call some `javaScript` function to `redirect` the page

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
   function redirectUser(){
       window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";

       window.navigate("http://www.yoururl.com"); //works only with IE
   }
</script>

<form>
    <button name="myBtn" value="Submit" onclick = "redirecrUser()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

2) You can create a link a bit `styling` it to look like button to `redirect`

```
<style>
    .linkToBtn{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: black;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<a href = 'yourUrl.com' class = 'linkToBtn'>Submit</a>
```

3) you can `redirect` it using the `PHP`

```
<form method = 'post' action = ''>
    <input type = 'submit' name = 'submitBtn' value = 'Redirect' />
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
        header('Location: yourURL.com');
    }
?>
```